# conservation of momentum?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, momentum, conservation-laws, collision, approximations

At [hyperphysics](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/imgmec/elacol4.gif) I got this image, with the same description in text as is in this image

[image: the image]

It says that when a massive particle (say $A$) moving with a velocity collides with an object having a relatively low mass (say $B$), then $B$ gains an velocity of $2v$ and the velocity of $A$ remains essentially unchanged.

Well, I agree with this fact because $A$ will create an acceleration in $B$ from a very far area, but $B$ will influence $A$ the least. So, here it appears like the law of conservation of momentum is violated? Can you please correct the fault that I have made in thinking about this phenomenon because conservation of momentum is not violated anywhere, or please just say that this source has provided the wrong information?

Comment: Conservation of momentum holds always. This is just an approximation. Plug in some numbers and you see why this approximation is valid.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Why do you say this violates conservation of momentum. The crucial part is *"remains **essentially** unchanged"*. It doesn't remain *exactly* unchanged.

Comment: my question is that why does the less massive object influence the more massive object at all  because as i already mentioned that A will create an acceleration in B from a very far area, but B will not influence A at that time

Comment: @FaizIqbal "<<" means "negligible compared to", $M_2$ is negligible compared to $M_1$, it's just an approximation, thats why he uses $\approx$ instead of $=$

Comment: @PabloSaudiBombsYemen

well , that does not make any change to the question that i am posing . i am saying why does velocity of the bigger atom decrease at all , even if b exerts a negligible force at it.

Comment: @FaizIqbal Please, plug in some numbers in the conservation of momentum formula and conservation of kinetic energy.

Comment: If B exerts *any* force on A, then the momentum of A *must* change, even if it's very small.

Comment: What do you mean by "$A$ will create an acceleration in $B$ **from a very far area**"?

Comment: @DanielGriscom
          Well , i am basically thinking about newtons law at the atomic level , i earlier have a post ( http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/231432/newtons-third-law-at-the-quantum-level/231502 ) which desribes how i  think about force at the atomic level . Well , using that explanation i find it hard to believe that a small mass will exert any considerable force on the large mass , but it is obvious that the large mass will exert a considerable amount of force on the small mass . So doesnt that violate newtons third law of motion and conservation of momentum ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is essentially the same question as 
https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/13302/

In a perfectly elastic collision, both momentum and kinetic energy are 
conserved.

The initial momentum is $\text{m1} \text{v1}$ and the initial kinetic 
energy is $\frac{\text{m1} \text{v1}^2}{2}$, since m2 is at rest.

Let u1 and u2 be the velocities of the two masses after the 
collision. By conservation of momentum and kinetic energy, 
this means:

$\text{m1} \text{u1}+\text{m2} \text{u2}=\text{m1}\text{v1}$

$ 
   \frac{\text{m1} \text{u1}^2}{2}+\frac{\text{m2} 
    \text{u2}^2}{2}=\frac{\text{m1} \text{v1}^2}{2} 
$

There are two solutions to these simultaneous equations, one of which 
is the initial condition (u1 = v1, u2 = 0). The other is:

$ 
   \left\{\text{u1}\to \frac{\text{v1} 
    (\text{m1}-\text{m2})}{\text{m1}+\text{m2}},\text{u2}\to \frac{2 \text{m1} 
    \text{v1}}{\text{m1}+\text{m2}}\right\} 
$

Since m2 is small, compared to m1, let's set `r=m2/m1` (which we 
expect to be a small number) in the solution:

$ 
   \left\{\text{u1}\to \frac{\text{v1}-r \text{v1}}{r+1},\text{u2}\to \frac{2 
    \text{v1}}{r+1}\right\} 
$

Now, as r approaches 0, we see that u1 approaches `(v1-0*v1)/(0+1)`, 
or v1, and u2 approaches `2*v1/(0+1)` or 2*v1

Comment: Thanks barrycarter ,
Will you please explain the same phenomen at the atomic scale, i want to know what is really happening !

Comment: Ultimately, collision is repulsion of electrons (the electromagnetic force) at the atomic level, but I'm not sure I feel qualified to explain the details there. In a body with more mass, the same force is spread out across more protons and neutrons, but I'll let someone else supply details.